# Filtro de información por medio de check box

Tags: excel, vba

Muchachos, estoy desarrollando un cotizador en excel usando vba. Mi pregunta es: Como hacer para filtrar la información dependiendo de las opciones que elija en los check box? Ya filtra por medio de la caja de texto, pero quiero a la vez pueda filtrar por otras opciones ya sea por dispositivo y tecnología por medio de la selección.
Este es el código del formulario kits.

```
Private Sub cbxlol_Change()

   NumeroD = Hoja1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Hoja1.AutoFilterMode = False
   Me.Lista = Clear
   Me.Lista.RowSource = Clear

   j = 0

   For Fila = 2 To NumeroD
      Descrip = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 7).Value

      'transformar informacion en mayuscula para facilitar la busqueda'
      If UCase(Descrip) Like "*" & UCase(Me.cbxlol.Value) & "*" Then      
         Me.Lista.AddItem
         'damos posicion listbox 0,0 excel comienza 1,1'

         Me.Lista.List(j, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 1).Value
         Me.Lista.List(j, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 2).Value
         Me.Lista.List(j, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 3).Value
         Me.Lista.List(j, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 4).Value
         Me.Lista.List(j, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 5).Value
         Me.Lista.List(j, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 6).Value
         Me.Lista.List(j, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 7).Value
         Me.Lista.List(j, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 8).Value

         j = j + 1
     End If      
  Next
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub txtLinea_Change()

   'Valor de la ultima fila'
   NumeroD = Hoja1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   Hoja1.AutoFilterMode = False
   Me.Lista = Clear
   Me.Lista.RowSource = Clear

   j = 0

   For Fila = 3 To NumeroD
      Descrip = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 6).Value    

     'transformar informacion en mayuscula para facilitar la busqueda'
     If UCase(Descrip) Like "*" & UCase(Me.txtLinea.Value) & "*" Then      
        Me.Lista.AddItem
        'damos posicion listbox 0,0 excel comienza 1,1'

        Me.Lista.List(j, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 1).Value
        Me.Lista.List(j, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 2).Value
        Me.Lista.List(j, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 3).Value
        Me.Lista.List(j, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 4).Value
        Me.Lista.List(j, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 5).Value
        Me.Lista.List(j, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 6).Value
        Me.Lista.List(j, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 7).Value
        Me.Lista.List(j, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 8).Value

        j = j + 1
    End If      
  Next    
End Sub
```

---

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()    
  Me.Lista.RowSource = "KITS2"    
  Me.Lista.ColumnCount = 8
  Me.Lista.ColumnWidths = "30;50;70;75;70;40;55"    
End Sub
```

Gracias
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podrías compartir tu código para que podamos ayudarte. Igual te invito a que des un [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) por el sitio para que tus preguntas puedan tener más impacto y puedan ser resueltas apropiadamente.

Comment: Compartí el código en la opción de respuestas.

Comment: Tu Código lo debes meter en tu pregunta, para ello existe la opción de editar tu pregunta, agregar el código, darle formato con las herramientas de stack para que sea más entendible a la comunidad.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basando en tu código que proporcionaste puedes:

- Usar el evento Change de tu Checkbox, recuerda que el componente
  CheckBox tiene únicamente dos valores (TRUE - ACTIVAR) y (FALSE -
  DESACTIVAR). Entonces cuando se activa el checkbox haces el mismo
  procedimiento de filtro variando en que ahora debes comparar datos de
  la columna Tecnología (para este ejemplo).

Anexo un código, he probado para un solo CheckBox para que filtre la columna **Tecnología** con el filtro *Aprobada*

> **Funciona de esta manera:** Si activa el CheckBox "Aprobada" se carga los
>   datos con el filtro correspondiente, cuando se desactiva el CheckBox
>   se limpia la lista.

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()
    If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
           Dim NumeroD As Integer
            Dim j As Integer
            NumeroD = Hoja1.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Hoja1.AutoFilterMode = False
            Me.Lista = Clear
            Me.Lista.RowSource = Clear
            j = 0

            For Fila = 1 To NumeroD
                If Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 8).Value = "Aprobada" Then
                    Me.Lista.AddItem
                    Me.Lista.List(j, 0) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 1).Value
                    Me.Lista.List(j, 1) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 2).Value
                    Me.Lista.List(j, 2) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 3).Value
                    Me.Lista.List(j, 3) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 4).Value
                    Me.Lista.List(j, 4) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 5).Value
                    Me.Lista.List(j, 5) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 6).Value
                    Me.Lista.List(j, 6) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 7).Value
                    Me.Lista.List(j, 7) = Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 8).Value
                    j = j + 1
                End If
            Next
            Else
            Me.Lista.Clear
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Viejo men, excelente. Ya realicé el proceso y tal como dices. Ahora tengo una duda, si selecciono por ejemplo analizador sin usar el textbox me filtra  solamente  dos datos, y deberían ser 4 datos.

Comment: Hiciste el cambio en esta isntruccion? **Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 8).Value = "Aprobada"**  a **Hoja1.Cells(Fila, 7).Value = "Analizador"** ?

Comment: Listo, ya solucionado. Ahora tengo que hacer lo mismo con los otros check box.  Cualquier cosa seguiré solicitando tu ayuda.Muchas gracias.